# datagrid created using usercontrol is not displaying in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I need to create a data-grid displaying only 6 rows and 0 columns. I had created an usercontrol which contains the datagrid with following

```
<sdk:DataGrid Grid.Column="1" x:Name="Customisedgrid" BorderBrush="GreenYellow"     
     BorderThickness="3" Background="Aqua" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
     HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="281" Margin="48,98,0,0" 
     Style="{StaticResource CustomDataGridStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
     Width="384" Itemsource ="{Binding S_BindData}"  
     CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellStyle1}">
```

Once my user control is ready I refer to it in mainpage.cs as below

```
private void ContentPanel_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  //instance of my usercontrol
  CustomGrid custom = new CustomGrid();
  //added my usercontrol to a stackpanel(GridOuterPanel)
  GridOuterPanel.Children.Add(custom);
}
```

My problem is, once I run my application I am not getting any data-grid I am viewing only a blank page...

Comment: You might want to tighted up your code. You'll get more help when it's easier to read and get into. I've helped you a bit on the way. Good questions BTW.

Comment: can you only check whether my user-control code has any error?

Comment: I could but I probably won't. When I come here and see this huge chunk of ill-formatted text, my browser feels my discomfort and navigates to an other web page. Maybe you can find someone else but my bet is that even they will ask you to 1. tighten up the code, 2. format the code and 3. to provide a minimal example telling people what you've done so far (this one is 100% sure to come up).

Comment: but i cant change code here and there becoz if i change anything it will become meaningless...but i will make  a try...

Comment: I think you're missing my point. Let me make it clearer. You're probably will get better help faster if you skip the part with "**THIS WHOLE SHABANG** is what I have - do it for me" and try to show a short piece of code in the ways of "THIS tiny part is not doing its stuff right". And if it's general question, skip the code all together.

Comment: ya i got your point and now i changed my code..